# How to get the type of a @property getter/setter?

Tags: python, class, types

Taking the below class and a class instance as an example:

```
class NewClass:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.number = a

    def func(self):
        return

    @property
    def test_property(self):
        return self.test_property


new = NewClass(1)
```

Trying to get the types for attributes and methods works:

```
>>> print(type(new.number))
int
>>> print(type(new.func))
method
```

Getting the type of an `@property` however results in a recursion error:

```
>>> print(type(new.test_property))
: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
return.RecursionError
```

How to get the type of an `@property` attribute?

Comment: Is the return value of `test_property` indeed supposed to be `self.test_property`?

Comment: A property belongs to the class using it. Try `print(type(NewClass.test_property))`.

Comment: Properties are just instances of descriptor classes, which are just objects that have  `__get__`, `__set__`, and `__delete__` methods. This means that what you're really asking is how to determine what type does the `__get__` method return. There's no way to know that, programmatically. It might even vary depending on the execution context. So your question is somewhat meaningless. You could make your own property class that had an additional method (or attribute) that returned or contained the information you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to define your property like this:

```
class NewClass:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.number = a

    def func(self):
        return

    @property
    def test_property(self):
        #return self.test_property  # Always going to call itself forever
        return self.number          # Maybe this is what you meant?
```

Comment: So an `@property` setter needs to have another variable which it uses to store state? The reason I want to use setters is to perform validation on the inputs (e.g. expected type, required length, etc). Would you say that having setters with private variables (_private_variable) is the best way to do this?

Comment: `property` is a way of setting or fetching an value, without having to use method syntax.  It's just a short hand.